# Set parameters on dropdown php

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 dropdown which are Court and Timeslot. I want it to be like this. When the 1st user select court A and select 8pm-9pm (1 hour slot) , then the 2nd user will not be able to see the items in the dropdown that the 1st user has selected. How should i do it? This is my codes:

```
<select name="court" required>
  <option value="">Court</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>


<select name="timeslot" required>
  <option value="">Time Slot</option>
  <option value="8.00 PM to 9.00 PM">8.00 PM to 9.00 PM (1 hour slot)</option>
  <option value="9.00 PM to 10.00 PM">9.00 PM to 10.00 PM (1 hour slot)</option>
  <option value="10.00 PM to 11.00 PM">10.00 PM to 11.00 PM (1 hour slot)</option>
  <option value="11.00 PM to 12.00 AM">11.00 PM to 12.00 AM (1 hour slot)</option>
  <option value="12.00 AM to 1.00 AM">12.00 AM to 1.00 AM (1 hour slot)</option>
  <option value="1.00 AM to 2.00 AM">1.00 AM to 2.00 AM (1 hour slot)</option>
  <option value="8.00 PM to 10.00 PM">8.00 PM to 10.00 PM (2 hours slot)</option>
  <option value="10.00 PM to 12.00 PM">10.00 PM to 12.00 AM (2 hours slot)</option>
  <option value="12.00 PM to 2.00 PM">12.00 AM to 2.00 AM (2 hours slot)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How are you storing the data the user selected? You would use that data to build the page the whichever user showing only times that haven't been chosen yet.

Comment: i put it into database.. but my friend told me for how long should Court A be unavailable to other users? Basically, you insert some data to a database, and check against that when creating the dropdown. If there's a match for Court A with the parameters you set, you don't display it in the dropdown

Comment: you need to use ajax pulling or websockets if you want this in real time

Comment: Your friend told you correctly, but you're not using that when you display the dropdowns. You need to query your db to find which times have already been selected.

Comment: allright.. thanks for the advice

Comment: you want to hide or disable the item 1st user selected

Comment: disable.. i think i have to do loop whenever the selected items exist in the database, it will no longer appear for the 2nd user dropdown menu..